# How to embed .NET modules into an independent assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies, al.exe

I'm trying to automate assembly generation from netmodules.
I tried to use "al.exe" tool with this commande line : al module1.netmodule module2.netmodule /target:library /out:assembly.dll.
My problem is that my assembly does not embed my netmodules but only references them :
 - if I open my assembly with "ildasm.exe" tool, I can only see the manifest
 - if I import my assembly in a new Visual Studio project, it does not work unless I copy the two netmodules beside the assembly

I tried the "ILMerge" tool, it seems to work fine on my simple example : the "ildasm.exe" tool shows the right classes and the assembly can be used in a Visual Studio project. But there are limitations (WPF) I fear to face further in my project.

My questions are :
 - Is there a way to produce an independant assembly from netmodules using "al.exe" or "csc.exe" ?
 - How to really embed netmodules into an assembly and not only reference them ?
 - Do I have to use "ILMerge.exe" ?
 - What is the real use of "al.exe" ? Can't "csc.exe" do the same using the "/addmodule" option ?

Comment: Erm, why are you using .netmodules?  What does that solve?  What's the real point to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Link.exe - it will do the job. You can find more details about the linker here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4(v=vs.71).aspx

The Link tool is installed as part of Visual Studio. In my machine Link.exe is installed at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64

The command structure that works for me is shown below:

```
LINK             = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\Link.exe"
LIBPATH1         = "$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\lib"
LIBPATH2         = "$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib"

$(LINK) /LIBPATH:$(LIBPATH1) /LIBPATH:$(LIBPATH2) /DLL /nologo /LTCG /out:$(DLL_NAME).dll $(EXT_MODULE1) $(EXT_MODULE2) $(EXT_MODULE3) ...
```